# Как избавиться от множества If

Tags: java

```
 @Override
public List<Position> aviableMove() {
    List<Position> positionList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        if ((x + i) <= 7 && f[x + i][y] == null) {
            positionList.add(new Position((x + i), y));
        } else break;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        if ((x - i) >= 0 && f[x - i][y] == null) {
            positionList.add(new Position((x - i), y));
        } else break;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        if ((y + i) <= 7 && f[x][y + i] == null) {
            positionList.add(new Position(x, (y + i)));
        } else break;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        if ((y - i) >= 0 && f[x][y - i] == null) {
            positionList.add(new Position(x, (y - i)));
        } else break;
    }
    return positionList;
}
```

этот метод-логика фигуры ладья из шахмат,метод возвращает все возможные ходы для фигуры по  текущему ее местоположению.Я вижу что код по сути дублируется ,но ничего не могу придумать ,чтобы не дублировать.Грубо говоря сверху вниз-первый цикл проверяет по оси х вправо,потом по оси х влево
и последние два цикла тоже самое с осью у.Сам иф записывает все клетки до тех пор пока не наткнется на клетку с фигурой - после этого вываливается из цикла
вопрос как мне избежать этих повторов?

Comment: Надо научиться видеть паттерны и уметь их правильно использовать. Лучшим набором паттернов выступает [GoF](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/gofpatterns.aspx).

Comment: И какой Вы тут видите паттерн?

Comment: Не тянет на ответ, даже названия паттерна не привели - поэтому это комментарий, а не ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пришлось изменить код , чтобы можно было его сделать лаконичнее:

```
 public static void iterate(Set<Position> positions, int px, int py){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        int mx = Math.max(0, Math.min(x + px*i, 7));
        int my = Math.max(0, Math.min(y + py*i, 7));
        // в реальной жизни вторая проверка не нужна, 
        // т.к. в этом месте стоит текущая фигура и первая проверка не пройдет
        if (f[mx][my] == null && !(mx==x && my==y)) 
            positions.add(new Position(mx, my));
        else break;
    }
}

public static Set<Position> aviableMove2() {
    Set<Position> positionList = new HashSet<>();
    iterate(positionList, 1,0);
    iterate(positionList, 0,1);
    iterate(positionList, -1,0);
    iterate(positionList, 0,-1);
    return positionList;
}
```

Простыня которой тестировал:

```html
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public class CheckMate {

    static Figure f[][] = new Figure[8][8];

    static int x, y;
    

    public static void iterate(Set<Position> positions, int px, int py){
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            int mx = Math.max(0, Math.min(x + px*i, 7));
            int my = Math.max(0, Math.min(y + py*i, 7));
            if (f[mx][my] == null && !(mx==x && my==y))
                positions.add(new Position(mx, my));
            else break;
        }
    }

    public static Set<Position> aviableMove() {
        Set<Position> positionList = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            if ((x + i) <= 7 && f[x + i][y] == null) {
                positionList.add(new Position((x + i), y));
            } else break;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            if ((x - i) >= 0 && f[x - i][y] == null) {
                positionList.add(new Position((x - i), y));
            } else break;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            if ((y + i) <= 7 && f[x][y + i] == null) {
                positionList.add(new Position(x, (y + i)));
            } else break;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            if ((y - i) >= 0 && f[x][y - i] == null) {
                positionList.add(new Position(x, (y - i)));
            } else break;
        }
        return positionList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
                test(i, j);
    }

    static void test(int tx, int ty) {
        x = tx;
        y = ty;
        Set<Position> moves1 = aviableMove();
        Set<Position> moves2 = aviableMove2();
        boolean eq = moves1.containsAll(moves2) && moves2.containsAll(moves1);
        System.out.println("test x=" + tx + " y=" + ty + " " + eq);
        if (eq)return;
        System.out.println(moves1);
        System.out.println(moves2);
        System.out.println("---");

    }



    public static Set<Position> aviableMove2() {
        Set<Position> positionList = new HashSet<>();
        iterate(positionList, 1,0);
        iterate(positionList, 0,1);
        iterate(positionList, -1,0);
        iterate(positionList, 0,-1);
        return positionList;
    }

    static private class Position {

        private final int x;
        private final int y;

        public Position(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + x + "," + y + "]";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Position position = (Position) o;
            return x == position.x &&
                    y == position.y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(x, y);
        }
    }

    static private class Figure {}
}
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93742/discussion-between---and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой метод, который правда генерирует `Set` возможных ходов.

```
public Set<Move> generateMoves(Position curPos) {
    Set<Move> moves = new HashSet<Move>();
    int curCol = curPos.getCol();
    int curRow = curPos.getRow();

    for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
        for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
            if (Math.abs(dx) != Math.abs(dy)) {
                int destCol = curCol + dx;
                int destRow = curRow + dy;
                while (ChessUtils.posBoundsTest(destRow, destCol)) {
                    Position destPos = new Position(destRow, destCol);
                    moves.add(new Move(curPos, destPos));

                    destCol = destCol + dx;
                    destRow = destRow + dy;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return moves;
}
```

`curCol` - это по вашему `x`, `curRow` - `y`

```
public class ChessUtils {
    public static boolean posBoundsTest(int row, int col) {
        return row >= 0 && row < 8 && col >= 0 && col < 8;
    }
}
```

Разберетесь или "перевести"?

Comment: это слишком не читаемо,этот код не пройдет code review

Comment: @Алексеевстанислав я бы не сказал что это прям не читаемо, однако 4 уровня вложенности немного напрягают :)

Comment: я про это и говорю,такой код завернут на код ревью 100%

Comment: Ну вам не угодишь))) сделайте extract method, будет покрасивее. Я этот код в свое время позаимствовал с рабочей игры шахматы... Меня бы больше напрягло то, что этот код не учитывает других фигур... Но тут, следуя правилам, никто на блюдечке не выкладывает всё готовое.